# Portletfilter to change locale?

Tags: java, filter, portlet, portal

the ServletResponse provides a setLocale() method to modify the locale of a response which is not commited yet. The PortletResponse doesn't provide such a method, only getLocale() - is there any other way to change the locale of a portlet request/response?

Comment: What Portlet API are you talking about?

Comment: @BalusC - I am assuming standard JSR168/JSR286 portlets.

Comment: At the moment i'm in a JBoss env, so the JBoss Portlet api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This would not be meaningful in portlets - they are only a component of an aggregate response.

The Portlet 2.0 spec (JSR 286) confirms this:

> The portlet cannot set the character encoding or the locale of the response as these are
>   pre-set by the portal / portlet container.